# Changing the default name of the table 'Users' to 'members' when using Kohana Auth

Tags: php, kohana

My table database have a table named 'members' instead  of 'users'. I have created a model for the members table using the following code

```
class Model_Member extends Model_Auth_User
```

While using the Auth module, the  following code is throwing an exception citing that the table 'users' doesn't exist. How can i make the look for the table 'members' instead of 'users'. or should i rename my table in the database?

Other Auth tables are named as below

> 'member_tokens', 'roles_members' and  'roles'

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a big deal, simply overwrite the `$_has_many` relationships, too.

```
class Model_Member extends Model_Auth_User {

    /**
     * A user has many tokens and roles
     *
     * @var array Relationhips
     */
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'member_tokens' => array('model' => 'Member_Token'),
        'roles'       => array('model' => 'Role', 'through' => 'roles_members'),
    );

    public function create_member($values, $expected)
    {
        $extra_validation = Model_Member::get_password_validation($values)
            ->rule('password', 'not_empty');

        return $this->values($values, $expected)->create($extra_validation);
    }

    public function update_member($values, $expected = NULL)
    {
        if (empty($values['password']))
        {
            unset($values['password'], $values['password_confirm']);
        }

        // Validation for passwords
        $extra_validation = Model_Member::get_password_validation($values);

        return $this->values($values, $expected)->update($extra_validation);
    }
}
```

And create model `Member_Token` and table `roles_members` (field name `member_id` instead of `user_id`)  accordingly.

```
class Model_Member_Token extends Model_Auth_User_Token {

    // Relationships
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'member' => array('model' => 'Member'),
    );

    protected function create_token()
    {
        do
        {
            $token = sha1(uniqid(Text::random('alnum', 32), TRUE));
        }
        while (ORM::factory('Member_Token', array('token' => $token))->loaded());

        return $token;
    }
}
```

I did **not** test the above code, it is simply made up to give you an idea of how to do it.

If you still get an exception, please post the exception message, too.